# When will I need to use binary search instead of linear search?

Tags: algorithm, search

How many binary searches need be performed in an `n-element` table to buy back the preprocessing time required to sort the table?

Comment: You're talking absolute time -- as in seconds and milliseconds?

Comment: That depends on the implementation details and can only be found out experimentally.

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: @AntonGogolev Now, I'm talking about times. `How many binary searches need be performed` 1,2,3, ... or 1000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a tricky question, because it depends on algorithm you use for sorting, binary search implementation details and so on.

Without knowledge of specific implementations, we can start analysis *only* in terms of Big-O notation (but it's not accurate, as complexity for algorithm O(2n) equal to O(n), but take roughly two times more)

**Analysis**

```
Binary search = O(logn)
Sorting       = O(nlogn)
Linear search = O(n)
```

You need to perform `K` searches. So for the raw unsorted array `a[n]` for different searches you need

**Binary Search**

1. Sort
2. Search `k` times

   TOTAL(BS) = O(logn) + k * O(logn)

**Linear Search**

1. Just search `k` times

   TOTAL(LS) = k * O(n)

Now, try to solve the equation, by comparing `k` and `n`

```
nlogn + klogn < kn
log(n^n) + log(n^k) < kn
log(n^(n+k)) < kn
n^(n+k) < 2^kn
2^kn - n^(n+k) > 0
```

*(I am not mathematician, this is as simplest as I can get)*

Now when you have input for your algorithms `N` and `K`, just evaluate last expression, to find minimum `K` to win with binary search.

**Example**

Assume n = 1000

2^(1000k) - 1000^(1000+k) > 0

This expression holds true when k > 10,
For n = 10000, expression holds true when k > 9

**Conclusion**

If you array is greather then 1000 elements, you need perform at least 10 binary searches to return sort investment

Comment: The numerical results only hold under the assumption, that all the constant factors hidden in the big-O notation are 1.

Comment: Your other "conclusion" should be that as `n` increases, `k` decreases. That is, the larger the array, the fewer searches you need to regain the time taken to sort it. Because `k*n` increases faster than does `(n+k)*log(n)`.

Answer (score -1):

Binary search is used when you have data in sorted order. Binary search will give you performance of O(logn). If you have more searches rather than insertions then binary search will give improved performance.  where as linear search is O(n). Linear search can be used when data is not order.